# Drag & Drop issue using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Dears,
Am trying to build a drag and drop functionality, where I shall move HTML fields like (Text field, check box, textarea, etc.)

the code is working fine with all type of input fields except for Check boxes and Radio buttons! it moves those two fields to wrong positions!

can you help plz?

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("ChkBox"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("TxtFld"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("RadioButton"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  var MouseMoveCounterVar = 0;
  
  document.getElementById(elmnt.id).onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    MouseMoveCounterVar = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup compaired to the window:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.FieldDrag {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0; background-color:silver">
<div id="ViewArea" style="width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <input id="TxtFld" type="text" class="FieldDrag" /><br/>
    <input id="ChkBox" type="checkbox" class="FieldDrag"/><br/>
    <input id="RadioButton" type="radio" class="FieldDrag"/><br/>
</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried everything, I checked the real positioning (clientX, clientY, offsetX, offsetY, screenX, screenY), it gives always correct coordinates but it keep shifting radio button and check box!

Comment: I tried to disable both radio button and check box but didn't work too!

Comment: I checked if the script calls the elementDrag function more than once by mistake, but it calls it correctly. The amazing thing that code works fine with all other fields (input text, div, image field, drop down list, file upload, etc...)!

Comment: I feel that the issue is due to the small width & height of those two fields (radio button & Check box). but how to overcome this?!

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you assume that the size of the fields is the culprit, why not resize them to test this hypothesis?

Comment: how can I change the size of a radio button or check box? I will try to add all clarification to the question, excuse me cuz its my first question here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save the element target by the drag in a variable (i call it inputField)

save the offset of the element at mousedown event

and change the calculation by

```
    inputField.style.left = (e.clientX + offset[0]) + 'px';
    inputField.style.top  = (e.clientY + offset[1]) + 'px';
```

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById("ChkBox"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("TxtFld"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("TxtFld2"));
dragElement(document.getElementById("RadioButton"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  var MouseMoveCounterVar = 0;
  var offset = [0,0];
  
  var inputField = document.getElementById(elmnt.id);
  inputField.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    MouseMoveCounterVar = 0;
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup compaired to the window:
   
    offset = [
      inputField.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
      inputField.offsetTop - e.clientY
    ];

    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
        inputField.style.left = (e.clientX + offset[0]) + 'px';
        inputField.style.top  = (e.clientY + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }

  function closeDragElement() {
    // stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.FieldDrag {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0; background-color:silver">
<div id="ViewArea" style="width: 100%; height:100%;position:relative; top:0; left:0;">
    <input id="TxtFld" type="text" class="FieldDrag" /><br/>
    <input id="ChkBox" type="checkbox" class="FieldDrag"/><br/>
    <input id="RadioButton" type="radio" class="FieldDrag"/><br/>
    <input id="TxtFld2" type="text" class="FieldDrag" /><br/>
</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: great work jeremy, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I replace those two fields with images and its working fine now, I treat them like moving an image not field.

Thanks for your time.